# Explanation of reduce example from mdn

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could somebody please give a elaborate explanation of this snippet

```
var names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Tiff', 'Bruce', 'Alice'];

var countedNames = names.reduce(function (allNames, name) { 
    if (name in allNames) {
        allNames[name]++;
    } else {
        allNames[name] = 1;
    }
    return allNames;
}, {});
```

Please explain the callback function how it takes the array names and brings out the answer

```
countedNames is:
// { 'Alice': 2, 'Bob': 1, 'Tiff': 1, 'Bruce': 1 }
```

Comment: This is a good article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reduce-f47a7da511a9

Comment: One of the best ways to learn how code works is to pretend you're the computer. Write the values of variables down on a piece of paper, and execute the code by hand.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I'll surely look into it , also it would be great if I know how allNames and name passed as arguments take the 'names' array and gives out the result

Comment: @Enthu If you've read the documentation of `reduce`, it explains how the arguments are passed and how the result is used.

Comment: ok thanks, as in dry run , got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This defines and array with 5 elements

```
var names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Tiff', 'Bruce', 'Alice'];
```

Let's define the function separately for ease of explaination

This function takes two parameters `(allNames, name)`. Whatever this function returns gets added to `allNames` at every iteration.

```
var myFunc = function (allNames, name) {
```

If `allNames` already contains the `name`, increment it's value

```
   if (name in allNames) {
        allNames[name]++;
    }
```

Otherwise, add `name` as the key and set it's value equal to `1`

```
    else {
        allNames[name] = 1;
    }
```

return `allNames` from this function so reduce can pass it as `allNames` next iteration

```
   return allNames;
}
```

This assigns the result of `.reduce()` to `countedNames` and `{}` is the initial value

```
var countedNames = names.reduce(myFunc, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it clearer here's the same code translated from functional to procedural

```
const names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Tiff', 'Bruce', 'Alice'];

const countedNames = {};
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  let name = names[i];
  // if exists increment, else set to 1
  if (countedNames[name] != null) {
    countedNames[name]++;
  } else {
    countedNames[name] = 1;
  }
}

console.log(countedNames);
```

In the reduce `{}` is the initial value and then each element of the array is run through the reduction function to modify the final value.